# Getting checked items,array is empty

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the ids of all checked checkboxes using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#thechecked").click(function(){
    var closestTr = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');

    var arr = $.map($(closestTr), function(e, i) {
        return +e.value;
    });
   alert(arr.join(','));
});
});
```

The example http://jsfiddle.net/3HS8P/1/ returns an empty array

Why is it returning an empty array?.

Comment: your question text and code are not consistent - did you want the IDs of the rows, or of the checked items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attr('id')` will only return the `id` of the first element, not all. You can map the collection directly.

```
$("#thechecked").click(function () {
    var arr = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').map(function(i, e) {
        return +e.id;
    }).get();
    alert(arr.join(','));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3HS8P/2

Doing a `.map` on a jQuery object will return a jQuery object, so you also need to do `.get()` to get the actual array, to be able to `.join()` its elements.

As @Alnitak pointed out in the comments below, CSS doesn't allow styling id's which start with a number (although it may work, it's not allowed by the spec.). I'd recommend using `data-id="1"` instead of `id="1"`, and then accessing it using `$(el).data("id")`.

Comment: why are you converting the ID into a number?

Comment: @Alnitak, just copied what OP was doing, I guess he/she probably wants to do some arithmetic on the values later.

Comment: @Alnitak, yes, I'd recommend using `data-` attributes, will add it to my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thechecked").click(function() {
        var closestTr = $('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr');
        var arr = closestTr.map(function(i, e) {
            return e.id;
        }).get();
       alert(arr.join(','));
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3HS8P/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your line ending `.attr('id')` is returning a string, not a set of elements, so you can't use it with `$.map`.  Try this generic example which will return all of the IDs for every element in the jQuery object `$el`:

```
var ids = $el.map(function(_, el) {
    return el.id;
}).get();
```

In your case, working bottom up, per your original code:

```
var $el = $(':checked').closest('tr');
```

or alternatively (and admittedly probably not very efficiently) working top down:

```
var $el = $('tr').has(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/3HS8P/5/

This will alert the row id which has checked check boxes.

```
$("#thechecked").click(function(){
    var all_ids = []
    var id = "";
    $.each($('input[type=checkbox]'),function(){
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked')
        if (checked){
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')
            all_ids.push(id)
        } 
    });
    alert(all_ids)
});
```

Comment: please learn how to use `.map` instead of a ` .each / push` combo.